# remove opencv 4.2 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, uninstallation

I tried to remove OpenCV 4.2 but failed.

I built it from the source,

First of all, used `$ opencv/build/ sudo make uninstall` I always use this method but today failed. it gave an error because I did not use `sudo ldconfig`  after `sudo make install` when it built, I guess. Anyway, I removed file build then OpenCV using many commands, from them:

```
 sudo apt remove libopencv*
sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
yes | sudo find / -name "*opencv*" -exec rm -i {} \;
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoremove opencv-doc opencv-data libopencv-dev libopencv2.4-java libopencv2.4-jni python-opencv libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-gpu2.4 libopencv-ts2.4 libopencv-photo2.4 libopencv-contrib2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4 libopencv-superres2.4 libopencv-stitching2.4 libopencv-ocl2.4 libopencv-legacy2.4 libopencv-ml2.4 libopencv-video2.4 libopencv-videostab2.4 libopencv-objdetect2.4 libopencv-calib3d2.4
```

and replace every 2.4 by 4.2, it gave me "no library"

and

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/include/opencv4 /usr/local/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv /usr/include/opencv4 /usr/local/share/opencv /usr/local/share/OpenCV /usr/share/opencv /usr/share/OpenCV /usr/local/bin/opencv* /usr/local/lib/libopencv*
```

something is strange, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

pip uninstall opencv-python

packages are usually installed in python using pip. this worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, It did not work with me, I formatted the whole PC. I thinke, it is important with opencv 4+ using $ opencv/build/ sudo make uninstall